# Cant understand when "salesrule_rule_condition_combine" hook called in magento?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.7

I have a old plugin for magento 1 and I am going to convert it to magento 2,I have a doubt.

there is a hook name :

```
'salesrule_rule_condition_combine'
```

I want to know when this hook will called in magento?